# mysql 8.0 cannot access via NodePort kubernetes

Tags: mysql, kubernetes, amazon-ec2, rancher, rancher-rke

i have mysql service on Rancher Kubernetes Engine and need to access via Nodeport for remote purpose. i already try with other service like elasticsearch and grafana dashboard and can be access via nodeport why mysql can't

here my service

```
kind: Service
metadata:
  labels:
    app: mysql
    service: mysql
  name: proxy-mysql-service
  namespace: x4-s24
spec:
  type: NodePort
  selector:
    app: mysql
  ports:
  - name: tcp-transfer
    port: 3306
    targetPort: 3306
    nodePort: 30036
```

statefulset

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: StatefulSet
metadata:
  name: mysql
  namespace: x4-s24
  labels:
     app: mysql
spec:
  replicas: 1
  updateStrategy:
    type: OnDelete
  serviceName: proxy-mysql-service
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: mysql
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: mysql
    spec:
      priorityClassName: high-priority
      containers:
        - image: mysql:8.0.26
          imagePullPolicy: Always
          name: mysql
          resources:
            requests:
              memory: 512Mi
              cpu: 200m
          ports:
          - containerPort: 3306
            name: tcp-mysql
            protocol: TCP
          env:
          - name: MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD
            valueFrom:
              secretKeyRef:
                name: mysql-secret
                key: mysql-password-root
          volumeMounts:
          - name: mysql
            mountPath: /var/lib/mysql
          - name: mysql-config
            mountPath: /etc/mysql/my.cnf
            subPath: my.cnf
      volumes:
        - name: mysql
          persistentVolumeClaim:
            claimName: mysql-8-pv
        - name: mysql-config
          configMap:
            name: mysql-configmap2
```

already add bind-address = 0.0.0.0 on my.cnf but still not working

Comment: How is your pod? It is active? What do you mean by "not working"?

Comment: the pods is active and can be access via port-forward

Comment: Could you set `NodePort` and then `kubectl get service`. Please paste your results to the question. You can also add some logs from your service.